# Calculate The time difference between prior row’s end_date and current row’s start_date in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below. Where I have to calculate the difference between the days of start date and end date.
But the calculation should be happening like below formula I have done for one row But I want it to be happening for all the rows.

```
df['start_date'][1]-df['end_date'][0]

  ship_id   start_date  end_date    days_difference
0   10  2016-10-05  2016-10-06  1 days
1   10  2016-10-07  2016-10-12  5 days
2   10  2016-10-22  2016-10-24  2 days
3   10  2016-10-29  2016-11-01  3 days
4   10  2016-11-04  2016-11-06  2 days
```

I have tried using for loop but its not giving correct output(below) Its giving 8-days for all the rows.

Used for loop

```
foo = range(1,len(df)) bar = range(len(df)) 
for f, b in zip(foo, bar):
   df['new_col'] = df['start_date'][f]-df['end_date'][b]
```

```
ship_id start_date  end_date    days_difference new_col
0   10  2016-10-05  2016-10-06  1 days  8 days
1   10  2016-10-07  2016-10-12  5 days  8 days
2   10  2016-10-22  2016-10-24  2 days  8 days
3   10  2016-10-29  2016-11-01  3 days  8 days
4   10  2016-11-04  2016-11-06  2 days  8 days
```

Expected output I want and at last I wanted to sum number of days group by ship_id

```
ship_id start_date  end_date    days_difference new_col
0   10  2016-10-05  2016-10-06  1 days  1 days
1   10  2016-10-07  2016-10-12  5 days  10 days
2   10  2016-10-22  2016-10-24  2 days  5 days
3   10  2016-10-29  2016-11-01  3 days  3 days
4   10  2016-11-04  2016-11-06  2 days
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `shift`:

```
df['new_col'] = df['start_date'].sub(df['end_date'].shift()).shift(-1)
print(df)

# Output
   ship_id start_date   end_date new_col
0       10 2016-10-05 2016-10-06  1 days
1       10 2016-10-07 2016-10-12 10 days
2       10 2016-10-22 2016-10-24  5 days
3       10 2016-10-29 2016-11-01  3 days
4       10 2016-11-04 2016-11-06     NaT
```

Or `df['end_date'].sub(df['start_date'].shift(-1)).abs()`